# Adding Conditional 'And' clause in Where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query, in which I need to conditionally add an 'AND' clause to the WHERE clause
I have a variable(@Payment) that only need including in the WHERE clause if it is NOT null.
I am not supposed to use IF condition.

Here is my code..

```
SELECT Fname,lname,city, addressline1, state,zip
FROM table1 
JOIN addresstable on table1.id = addresstable.addid
WHERE state = @state
AND ((@Payment IS NULL) OR (payment LIKE + '%' + @Payment + '%' ) OR (payment LIKE + '%all%' ) )
```

In the example, if @Payment IS NULL then I don't want the last 'AND' clause added to where clause.

Comment: For which technology you are working and which sql database u are using??

Comment: and are u using asp.net??

Comment: yes, but why does it matter?, this is a stored proc

Comment: exactly... now you can do one thing. Take a @query variable. And in that query through asp.net pass your condition. so no need of if condition in your sp.

Comment: Hi Rony, unfortunately I cannot pass anything from asp.net

Comment: Hi Loc, When @payment is null its not working, its not returning any values

Comment: Does this not work when you run it from the SQL Management Studio query designer or does it not work when calling the stored procedure from ASP.Net?

Comment: When you are commenting on an answer, please add your comment under that answer, not under your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select fname,lname,city, addressline1, state,zip
from table1 
join addresstable on table1.id = addresstable.addid
where state = @state
and (
      (@Payment is null)
      or 
      (payment like @PaymentLike)
)
```

When you call this query. You need pass 2 parameters.

- @Payment
- @PaymentLike

Assume you pass 'payment' variable to @Payment

You will pass: (payment == null) ? "%all%" : ("%" + payment + "%") to @PaymentLike

Sure this work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide any test data or your schema, so it's a quite hard to say for certain, but this may be what you need.

I'm not sure of the purpose of this condition `OR (payment LIKE + '%all%' )` it will restrict results to all rows that contain the word "all".

I have assumed (although you don't state it in your question) that you are trying to return all the rows from addresstable and any matching rows from table1. using a [left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).  If this isn't the case you can move this `AND ((payment LIKE + '%' + COALESCE(@Payment,'') + '%' ) OR (payment LIKE + '%all%' ) )`  back to the WHERE clause and change the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN.

```
--Test data
DECLARE @table1 AS TABLE(addid INT, payment VARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @addresstable AS TABLE(addid INT, Fname VARCHAR(20),lname VARCHAR(20),city VARCHAR(20), addressline1 VARCHAR(20), [state] VARCHAR(20),zip VARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @Payment AS VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @state VARCHAR(20)
SET @state='stateA'
INSERT INTO @table1 (addid, payment) VALUES(1,'payment 1')
INSERT INTO @table1 (addid, payment) VALUES(3,'payment 2')
INSERT INTO @table1 (addid, payment) VALUES(4,'payment 3')
INSERT INTO @table1 (addid, payment) VALUES(5,'payment 4')

INSERT INTO @addresstable (addid, Fname, lname, city, addressline1, [state], zip) VALUES (1, 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'stateA', 'A')
INSERT INTO @addresstable (addid, Fname, lname, city, addressline1, [state], zip) VALUES (2, 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'stateA', 'B')
INSERT INTO @addresstable (addid, Fname, lname, city, addressline1, [state], zip) VALUES (3, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'stateA', 'C')
INSERT INTO @addresstable (addid, Fname, lname, city, addressline1, [state], zip) VALUES (4, 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'stateB', 'D')
INSERT INTO @addresstable (addid, Fname, lname, city, addressline1, [state], zip) VALUES (5, 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'stateB', 'E')

--Query
SELECT Fname,lname,city, addressline1, state,zip, payment
FROM @addresstable a
LEFT JOIN @table1 t
    ON t.addid = a.addid
    AND ((payment LIKE + '%' + COALESCE(@Payment,'') + '%' ) OR (payment LIKE + '%all%' ) )
WHERE [state] = @state
```

Comment: Have you found any of the answers useful?  Do you have any questions?  Could you supply any test data?